# How display form in HTML intergration DRF and django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi I have problem with intergration DRF and django-filters.
How to display filters form in my HTML like in DRF API views. I was trying use @action decorator but that no works me. Someone have a idea how solve this problem ?

```
class AlbionViewsSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Albion_data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Albion_data_Serializer
    filterset_class = Itemfilters
    lookup_field = "item"
```

Answer (score 1):

**filterset_class** you are setting belongs to DjangoFilterBackend class, so in order to make it work, you have to set **filter_backends** field in your ViewSet. Most probably the following is what you want:

```
class AlbionViewsSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Albion_data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Albion_data_Serializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = Itemfilters
    lookup_field = "item"
```

Comment: I would display form on my own html file. I added filter_backend but this still is't working.